# Does Serializable isolation level block read queries in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, rdbms

I have table "Transactions", where customers accounts transactions will be hold. So I want to set transaction level Serializable to prevent all types of anomalies.

Lets assume transactions goes this way:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
INSERT INTO transaction_test (sum, currency) VALUES (333, '820');
```

I doubt whether this table will be accessible for users to read, because our Application needs to run multiple SELECTs from this table for statistics?

After some googling I'm confused a little bit:

- From the one hand Postgres [PostgreSQL actually treats every SQL statement as being executed within a transaction.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html), so regular SELECT query for the data could be blocked
- From the other hand [that “readers never block writers” and “writers never block readers.”](https://www.dbvis.com/thetable/getting-started-with-multiversion-concurrency-control-mvcc-in-postgresql/#:%7E:text=The%20Behavior%20of%20MVCC,can%20see%20in%20a%20database.) due Postgres MVCC.

**So the question is:** can the **Transaction** table be safely use for SELECT queries in parallel of being changed with transactions of SERIAL level isolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not guarantee `SERIALIZABLE` by locking out every potentially conflicting transactions. Rather, it takes special *predicate locks*, which don't block anything, but track what data a transaction has read. If a situation arises that could violate serializability, PostgreSQL would abort one of the transactions with a *serialization error*.

Concurrent read-only transactions won't be blocked. As recommended by [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE), you should wrap read-only queries in a `SERIALIZABLE READ ONLY` transaction for best performance.